# Why does Go source contain many .go files? How do they get compiled?

Tags: gcc, go, compilation, compiler-construction, cross-compiling

i want know how go compiler work!

https://github.com/golang/go
this source Contains 88% `.go` file.

so this should be have another compiler to execute `.go` file.

Example : https://github.com/golang/go/blob/964639cc338db650ccadeafb7424bc8ebb2c0f6c/src/go/ast/ast.go

Golang use what compiler for final Generate Execute file?! and where available they source?

may be Golang generate a c code and next use GCC or ...?

### New Update

i not want go1.4 then in using c.

88% source of github.com/golang/go is `.go` file. what compile `.go` file at Go Source? i want see Final GO Compiler?

https://github.com/golang/go/search?l=c

i think this called `cg`.

---

mean An old version of Go compiler (version 1.4) is used to compile newer version of Go compiler.???!

`go-go1.4.3/src/go/token/token.go` this is go token,lexer and is write at GO

`FUNC:   "func",
    GO:     "go",
    GOTO:   "goto",
    IF:     "if",
    IMPORT: "import",`

### so where main compiler for execute `.go` file?

`go-go1.4.3/src/runtime/compiler.go`

```
// Copyright 2012 The Go Authors.  All rights reserved.
package runtime
// Compiler is the name of the compiler toolchain that built the
// running binary.  Known toolchains are:
//
//  gc      The 5g/6g/8g compiler suite at code.google.com/p/go.
//  gccgo   The gccgo front end, part of the GCC compiler suite.
//
const Compiler = "gc"
```

---

### go-go1.4.3/src/cmd/gc$ make

```
go tool dist install -v
make: go: Command not found
../../Make.dist:13: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 127
```

make gc why need Go?!

---

### Last version of GO Language how work?! mean how this generate a output for cross platform? this use generate code to C and then use c compiler?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)

Comment: tanks you , So go is a self-hosting compiler, so what execute and run `.go` file at https://github.com/golang/go ?

Comment: Also note that the majority of what's in github.com/golang/go is the standard library, not the compiler.

Comment: woow , where available compiler source? @Adrian

Comment: Same repo. It's the compiler, tools, standard library, tests, and documentation, it's all there.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go , Original/Final Compiler for `.go` is write at `.c`? https://github.com/golang/go/search?l=c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://golang.org/doc/go1.5#implementation and https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/01/golang-15-bootstrapped , Go was originally implemented in C but became self-hosted at version 1.5. Bootstrapping is the process of compiling a compiler with itself. The Go developers wrote a C -> Go transpiler to convert the original C compiler to Go, then they hand-edited the Go code to make it idiomatic.

Comment: tanks you , if go is a self-hosting compiler , so use ASM for execute and parse .go file?

Comment: The Go compiler written in Go is used to compile itself, but the original Go compiler was written in C and compiled using a C compiler.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the Go compiler because I see Go code right from the branch of the first release... Nevertheless, you should take a peek around https://github.com/golang/go , and also read https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OaatvGhEAq7VseQ9kkavxKNAfepWy2yhPUBs96FGV28/edit#! .

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#What_compiler_technology_is_used_to_build_the_compilers , how can see Gc original compiler of go? is open source?

Comment: @Nahad, if by "original" you mean "written in C", then just check out the branch "release1.4" from the Go's Git repository, or the branches for any earlier version.

Comment: i want see source of original compiler(last version Go).

Comment: @Nahad What do you mean by original? Current version can be found in https://github.com/golang/go older version that implemented with C can be found in older branches like https://github.com/golang/go/tree/release-branch.go1.4

Comment: i not want go1.4 then in using c.  88% source of https://github.com/golang/go is `.go` file. what compile `.go` file at Go Source? i want see Final GO Compiler?

Comment: @Nahad An old version of Go compiler (version 1.4) is used to compile newer version of Go compiler. Furthermore, not all files in git repository are related to compiler lots of them are standard library.

Comment: `go-go1.4.3/src/go/token/token.go` this is go lexer and is write at go so where main compiler?  , 
 FUNC:   "func",
 GO:     "go",
 GOTO:   "goto",
 IF:     "if",  @ArmanOrdookhani

Comment: @Nahad Those file was not used in the compiler itself and intended for people want to parse go files. I think go compiler used yacc for lexing that time.

Comment: i want see source of main compiler for parse and execute `.go` file? where can see this? @ArmanOrdookhani

Comment: main compiler is `GC`? where available source of main compiler?

Comment: @Nahad See this file it's compiler entry point https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.4/src/cmd/gc/lex.c#L199 gc directory is compiler architecture-independent parts.

Comment: so all code/files of main compiler at `go-go1.4.3/src/cmd/gc`?  , all is c and 1.1MB file.

Comment: if parser of go is `go-go1.4.3/src/cmd/gc/go.y` . so why also another parser at `go-go1.4.3/src/go/parser/parser.go` ?

Comment: go-go1.4.3/src/cmd/gc$ make
----------------

    go tool dist install -v
    make: go: Command not found
    ../../Make.dist:13: recipe for target 'install' failed
    make: *** [install] Error 127

---------------- , make at gc also need go!? :|||| @ArmanOrdookhani

Comment: @Nahad You should run `make.bash`. If there is a problem make another question about compiling old go lang compiler.

Comment: Last version of GO Language how work?! mean how this generate a output for cross platform? this use generate code to C and then use c compiler? @ArmanOrdookhani